# How push-link.com performs its updates NINJA (Update silently) and Status_Bar (Update from the notification bar)?

Tags: android

I'm investigating as [push-link](http://www.push-link.com/index.html) upgrade makes these types of applications and I cannot find information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open-source alternative [AutoUpdateAPK](http://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/), feel free to download sources and see how it works.

Comment: I just want to add that the server is not open-source (only the client) and as far as I can tell cannot be self-hosted. Unfortunately that does not work for my specific situation :-(.

Comment: @Joe the question was not about the server part, it was about the client side, where the .apk replacement takes place. sorry about your specific situation, though.